# .htaccess RewriteRule for https specific prefix urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Am wanting to create the `https://` protocols on just these prefix urls on my site:

`dream-portal.net/index.php?page=postratingspro`

and

`dream-portal.net/index.php?page=paypaltest`

So anything in the URL after this should also include `https://` protocol.  For example:

`dream-portal.net/index.php?page=postratingspro;sa=blahblah;testing`

How can I do this?  Have tried the following, but it doesn't turn all of my other urls to http:// on the site.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} = off
RewriteRule index.php?page=^(postratingspro|paypaltest)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# don't do anything for images/css/js (leave protocol as is)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ - [NC,L]

# force http for all other URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} = on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !page=^/(postratingspro|paypaltest)\$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

How can I accomplish this, what is wrong with my code for this?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=(paypaltest|postratingspro)[&;,\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)page=(paypaltest|postratingspro)([,;&]|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: I just replaced it, but when people browse to:  https://dream-portal.net/index.php?action=forum it stays as `https`, how can I change this to `http`?  Basically, it should change all urls that don't match to `http` protocol.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect!  You're the BEST!  This stuff is way over my head!

Comment: WAIT - but any string after it doesn't work:  for example:  https://dream-portal.net/index.php?page=postratingspro;sa=thankyou goes to `http` page instead of `https`